# Web Crawler URL results not exact

Tags: java, http, url, jsoup, web-crawler

I've just made my first web crawler, my goal was simply to go on www.nhl.com, and create a database that contains every anchor and button, as well as the URL that they forward to.

The code seems to be working fine, but I have two questions about the output.

Here are two examples of URL entries in my database:

1.`http://www.nhl.com/ice/event.htm?location=/stadiumseries/2014/chi/responsive`

2.`/ice/m_events.htm`

Why do some record the entire URL, whereas others only have the second part of it?
[ANSWERED]

Second question, take for example this row entry:

`9 Players /ice/m_playersearch.htm`, which is in the form [id, anchor, url]

When I go to the website in my browser and click on "Players", the URL in my browser becomes:

`http://www.nhl.com/ice/playersearch.htm?navid=nav-ply-plyrs#`

which has a second part to the URL that my table entry does not (`?navid=nav-ply-plyrs#`)

Having said that, entering the URL given to me by my database still ends up redirecting me to the same page, so it doesn't seem to be a mistake. I'm just wondering why/how it's able to determine that the second part of the URL  is not needed.

Here is part of my code:

```
public void crawl(String url){

    try{
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        Elements pgElem = doc.select("a");
        int id = 0;

        for(Element e : pgElem){
            db.insert(id, e.text(), e.attr("href"));
            id++;
        }

        db.close();   

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And my insert method:

```
 public void insert(int id, String anchor, String url) {

    String string = "INSERT INTO nhl (id,Anchor,URL) " + "VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    try {
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(string);
        pst.setInt(1, id);
        pst.setString(2, anchor);
        pst.setString(3, url);
        pst.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `e.attr("href")` to `e.attr("abs:href")` to get absolute urls.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the first issue, but what about the second one? The URL still stops short of `?navid=nav-ply-plyrs#`